# Using GL_OES_get_program_binary(compiled shaders) on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I'm looking to use GL_OES_get_program on Android using the Android SDK (not native).

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_get_program_binary.txt

The Android SDK allows to upload shaders in binary format, but how can I get the binary from the driver in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of retrieving the program binary is, that after supplying the OpenGL(-ES) implementation with the shader source code, you receive back the compiled binary to cache it. If the driver or the OS version changes, it might be necessary to recompile the sources. So the shader binary program interface is not meant for shipping a shader binary only.

You retrieve the shader binary by calling `glGetProgramBinaryOES`. Franky, I don't really understand your problem, because the specifcation text you linked has example code at the end.

Comment: " Franky, I don't really understand your problem, because the specifcation text you linked has example code at the end."
The code isn't in Java. 
"you receive back the compiled binary to cache it"
Yep that's what I want. Shader compiling takes too long otherwise.

Comment: @Zammbi: Sorry, didn't catch the Java bit. Well, you normally instanciate some byte buffer (instead of malloc) and pass that instead of a pointer to the function.